# Google PHP SDK - not getting refresh token

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to get a refresh token for the Google API's, using the PHP SDK. I am authenticating the user with Javascript, retrieving a code, and exchanging it for an access_token server side, but this doesn't grant me an access token. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code I use:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me');
$client->addScope('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_REQUEST['code']);
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
        $result['data']=$token_data;
        $result['access_token']=json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
}

debug($result); //my own function, var_dumps the content of an array
```

Here is the result of the array:

$result['access_token'] contains:

> access_token: **TOKEN**
>   created: 1434380576
>   expires_in: 3594
>   id_token: **IDTOKEN**
>   token_type:"Bearer"

If I am not mistaken the first access token should also contain the refresh token, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the settings in the developer console of Google to see if your RedirectUri is the same and that the API is activated (although if you already got that .json, then I assume it is.

You have to go through the Google Auth Prompt Screen at least 1 time to get a refresh token in your .json, and if your RedirectUri is taking you nowhere, you won't be able to get your refresh token or even the access validated.

You can also try a service account if you're doing small file transactions and don't need a user validation for the process of your script. Good Luck.

Comment: The redirectURI I use, is not an url, because the authentication is being done client side, via Javascript. I don't know what should I check in the Developer Console at the RedirectUri. The Google Auth Prompt Screen is being fired client side, and I am retrieving a code with which I authenticate my user server side(PHP). I need the authentication to be client side, because my webpage is ajax controlled, without redirects. I also tried revoking the access to my App, with no success:|

Comment: If the client side is doing the auth, then you need to retrieve the refresh token from javascript and send it as parameter. To this script, you're not authorized as it can't know you already triggered your javascript. Try storing the credentials (that .json) from the javascript or at least the "refresh_token" field and use it in the script to get auto authorization.

Comment: Your line  $client->authenticate($_REQUEST['code']); should generate an access token and a refresh token. The access token has a short amount of lifespan so its advised that you use the refresh token instead. When you do  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); you lose the refresh token that was in the previous json. 

So, long story short: 

`code(tokens=$client->authenticate($_REQUEST['code']);
 $_SESSION['refresh_token']= tokens['refresh_token];)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to specify that I want offline access in the authentication process, the client side... The Google API's are horribly documented!!!